# Using noexcept as a lambda modifier or parameter constraint

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, noexcept

Can the `noexcept` modifier be applied to a lambda expression? If so, how?

Can `noexcept` be made a constraint on a function argument? For example, something like in the following code, where the meaning is that the callback function must be `noexcept`?

```
//probably not valid code - I'm just trying to express the idea
void f_async(std::function<void (int) noexcept> callback) noexcept
{
    ...
}
```

This can *almost* be accomplished with the following code, but I'm wondering if there is a way to use something like the above alternative.

```
void f_async(std::function<void (int)> callback)
    noexcept(callback(std::declval<int>()))
{
    ...
}
```

The problem here of course is that `f_async` can be `noexcept(false)` if the callback is `noexcept(false)` - I want to make a stronger statement that `f_async` is *always* `noexcept`, meaning it's only callable if you use a `noexcept` callback.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Can the `noexcept` modifier be applied to a lambda expression? If so, how?

Add `noexcept` after the parenthesis:

```
[](Args args) noexcept { ... }
```

---

> Can `noexcept` be made a constraint on a function argument?

Yes, use enable_if:

```
template <typename F>
auto f_async(const F& func) noexcept 
        -> typename std::enable_if<noexcept(func(0))>::type {
    func(0);
}

int main() {
    f_async([](int x) noexcept {});
    f_async([](int x) {}); // <- this line won't compile
}
```

**However**, this method cannot work directly in g++ 4.7 (it does work in clang++ 3.2), because it cannot mangle `noexcept` expression yet:

> 3.cpp:5:6: sorry, unimplemented: mangling noexcept_expr

You could workaround it using a wrapper struct:

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>
struct EnableIfNoexcept 
        : std::enable_if<noexcept(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Args>()...))> {};

template <typename F>
auto f_async(const F& func) noexcept -> typename EnableIfNoexcept<F, int>::type {
    func(0);
}
```

Comment: Interesting - I haven't really seen this `std::enable_if` before. Looks promising.

Comment: Nice try, but does not work when pass free function to f_async in clang 3.5.

Comment: The `sorry, unimplemented: mangling noexcept_expr` error also occurred on `g++ 7.3`. So can I ask which version of g++ can compile above code?

Comment: How does one add noexcept if the parameter list was omitted?

Comment: @Silicomancer Before C++23, you can't omit the parameter list in that case: `[]() noexcept {...}` - In C++23: `[] noexcept { ... }`

Answer (score 8):

Concerning the first question:

> Can the noexcept modifier be applied to a lambda expression? If so, how?

Yes, just add the exception specification after the parameter list:

```
[] (int i) noexcept { return i * 1; };
//         ^^^^^^^^
```

Per paragraph 5.1.2/5 of the C++11 Standard:

> The closure type for a lambda-expression has a public inline function call operator (13.5.4) whose parameters
>   and return type are described by the lambda-expression’s parameter-declaration-clause and trailingreturn-
>   type respectively. This function call operator is declared const (9.3.1) if and only if the lambda-expression’s
>   parameter-declaration-clause is not followed by mutable. It is neither virtual nor declared
>   volatile. Default arguments (8.3.6) shall not be specified in the parameter-declaration-clause of a lambda-declarator.
>   **Any exception-specification specified on a lambda-expression applies to the corresponding function
>   call operator**. An attribute-specifier-seq in a lambda-declarator appertains to the type of the corresponding
>   function call operator. [ Note: Names referenced in the lambda-declarator are looked up in the context in
>   which the lambda-expression appears. —end note ]